# Insert HTML with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, append

If I have a block of HTML like:-

```
<div id="t1">
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="Bla"/>
    </div>
    <!--INSERT JQUERY HTML HERE--> </div>
```

How would I go about inserted HTML generated by a user click where my comment is? On each user action, I'd need to insert a block of code which will follow something like:

```
<div id="block1"><span>bla bla bla</span></div>
```

so in theory after several clicks we could end up with something like:

```
<div id="t1">
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="Bla"/>
    </div>
    <div id="block1"><span>bla bla bla</span></div>.
    <div id="block2"><span>bla bla bla</span></div>.
    <div id="block3"><span>bla bla bla</span></div>.
</div>
```

I'm aware of the `append()` function but I'm unsure as to if this will work here.

If anyone has any better solution to the HTML code, then please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [append works nice](http://jsfiddle.net/MmHrg/):

```
$('#t1').append('<div id="block1"><span>bla bla bla</span></div>');
```

Comment: However this will not support the exactly what the OP wants. Just make the id `block` generic with a counter and it should be fine

Comment: Are you sure append will work? Won't it just add onto the end of #t1? I want it to appear inside #t1 before the closing div. Plus any further additions to be sequential after that.

Comment: Haven't you looked at the link? Analyzing it with FireBug it does exactly what you expect.

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't see the link, that appears to work perfectly. Thank you.